# how do i post multiple images in cloudinary from my react applicatio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, cloudinary

i want to be able to post multiple images in an array  in cloudinary all at once , i made a solution that cant post it one at a time. I tried tinkering with foreach loop and other loop but couldnt get a hold of it

```
 const uploadImages = async () => {
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append('file', files)
        data.append("upload_preset", "uploads")


        try {
            const upload = await axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/**********/image/upload", data)
            

            const { url } = upload.data
            console.log(url);
            alert("Upload")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

The files in line 3, is an array of images . the function uploadImages  will be kept in onclick . On the click of the function it should be activated and all images be sent

Answer (score 0):

Danny from Cloudinary Support here.

I'm afraid a bulk upload with an array isn't possible - as mentioned in our [How can I bulk upload my images?](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520662-How-can-I-bulk-upload-my-images-) article, our Upload API only supports a single file per API call.

If you need to upload multiple assets in a friendly way, I would recommend implementing our Upload Widget. An example for doing this with React can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cld-uw-uymkb

I hope this helps. If you need any further support, I would recommend opening up a ticket via our support center: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Thanks,

-Danny